# ¿De qué otra manera puedo decir "nos sentimos muy orgullosos de"?

Tags: sinónimos

¿De qué otra manera puedo decir: "nos sentimos muy **orgullosos** de poder", utilizando un sinónimo para la palabra "orgullosos"?

Comment: Si lo que quieres es cambiar la palabra porque suena mal en esa posición o porque su significado se confunde con el de "altanero", puedes probar **nos enorgullece poder** o **nos llena de orgullo poder**

Answer (score 5):

Bueno es que, **"orgullosos"** ya denota un tipo de sentimiento muy específico.

Podrías elegir otra palabra, pero definitivamente cambiaría el sentido o significado contextual...

Pienso en:

"Nos sentimos **halagados** de poder..."

"Nos sentimos **agraciados** de poder..."

"Nos sentimos **honrados** de poder..."

---

O quizás replanteando la frase:

"Representa un honor para nosotros poder..."

Answer (score 2):

[Según WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/sinonimos/orgulloso), algunos sinónimos para **orgulloso** en la acepción en que la quieres usar son: ***satisfecho, contento, optimista, ufano, gozoso***.

> Nos sentimos muy satisfechos de poder...
>   Nos sentimos muy contentos de poder...
>   Nos sentimos muy ufanos de poder...

Personalmente, no usaría *optimista* ni *gozoso*, no terminan de cuadrarme.

Comment: Gozoso me gusta. Satisfecho también cuadra bien - porque puede ser que dicha satisfacción venga después de un gran esfuerzo...